# How to draw a rectangle on a graph with XY axes Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw a rectangle on a graph with XY axes using Qt. I have found [QCustomPlot](http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/introduction) widget, but it is not what i need (or i did not understand how to apply it to solve my problem).[image]

[image]

Please any suggestions how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding [QCPItemRect](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPItemRect.html) to [QCPLayer](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPLayer.html) of `QCustomPlot`. It seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: if someone would like to get the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444939/qcustomplot-show-item-on-qcpaxisrect-below-customplot)

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of what you need:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

class MyPlot : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyPlot(QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
    }


protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);

        painter.save();
        painter.translate(2, height() -2); // 2 pixels between axes and the windows frame
        painter.scale(1,-1);

        QPen pen;
        pen.setWidth(2);
        painter.setPen(pen);

        // X Axis
        painter.drawLine(0,0, width(),0);

        // Y Axis
        painter.drawLine(0,0, 0,height());

        pen.setWidth(4);
        painter.setPen(pen);

        // Rect
        painter.drawRect(10,10, 60,80);

        painter.restore();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest override paintEvent in QWidget:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
  Q_UNUSED(event);
  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.drawLine(0, 10, 100, 10);
  painter.drawLine(10, 0, 10, 100);
  painter.drawRect(20, 20, 30, 30);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use just the plain `QWidget` and reimplement it's `paintEvent()` function. The painting would be realized by the `QPainter`.

```
void CMyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawLine(...);
    p.drawRect(...);
    p.drawText(...);
}
```

Or you can use a `QGraphicsView` / `QGraphicsScene` framework: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html